# How to change Class code into Function code for Ant Design Tabs customization

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd, ant-design-pro, antd-mobile

I am changing the class code into function code for customizing Ant Design Tabs .
Everything is working fine but I am not able to change onEdit function. How can I do it.

Here is the code inside Class

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Tabs, Button } from 'antd';

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.newTabIndex = 0;
    const panes = [
      { title: 'Tab 1', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 1', key: '1' },
      { title: 'Tab 2', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 2', key: '2' },
    ];
    this.state = {
      activeKey: panes[0].key,
      panes,
    };
  }

  onChange = activeKey => {
    this.setState({ activeKey });
  };

  onEdit = (targetKey, action) => {
    this[action](targetKey);
  };

  add = () => {
    const { panes } = this.state;
    const activeKey = `newTab${this.newTabIndex++}`;
    panes.push({ title: 'New Tab', content: 'New Tab Pane', key: activeKey });
    this.setState({ panes, activeKey });
  };

  remove = targetKey => {
    let { activeKey } = this.state;
    let lastIndex;
    this.state.panes.forEach((pane, i) => {
      if (pane.key === targetKey) {
        lastIndex = i - 1;
      }
    });
    const panes = this.state.panes.filter(pane => pane.key !== targetKey);
    if (panes.length && activeKey === targetKey) {
      if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        activeKey = panes[lastIndex].key;
      } else {
        activeKey = panes[0].key;
      }
    }
    this.setState({ panes, activeKey });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          <Button onClick={this.add}>ADD</Button>
        </div>
        <Tabs
          hideAdd
          onChange={this.onChange}
          activeKey={this.state.activeKey}
          type="editable-card"
          onEdit={this.onEdit}
        >
          {this.state.panes.map(pane => (
            <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
              {pane.content}
            </TabPane>
          ))}
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

And here is my code inside the function

```
const initialPanes = [
  { title: "Tab 1", content: "Content of Tab 1", key: "1" },
  {
    title: "Tab 2",
    content: "Content of Tab 2",
    key: "2",
    closable: true,
  },
];

const Curriculum = (props) => {
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(initialPanes[0].key);
  const [panes, setPanes] = useState(initialPanes);

  var newTabIndex = 0;

  const onChange = (activeKey) => {
    setActiveKey(activeKey);
  };

  const add = () => {
    const activeKey = `newTab${newTabIndex++}`;
    const newPanes = [...panes];
    newPanes.push({
      title: "New Tab",
      content: "Content of new Tab",
      key: activeKey,
    });
    setActiveKey(activeKey);
    setPanes(newPanes);
  };

  const remove = (targetKey) => {
    let newActiveKey = activeKey;
    let lastIndex;
    panes.forEach((pane, i) => {
      if (pane.key === targetKey) {
        lastIndex = i - 1;
      }
    });
    const newPanes = panes.filter((pane) => pane.key !== targetKey);
    if (newPanes.length && newActiveKey === targetKey) {
      if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        newActiveKey = newPanes[lastIndex].key;
      } else {
        newActiveKey = newPanes[0].key;
      }
    }
    setPanes(newPanes);
    setActiveKey(newActiveKey);
  };

  const onEdit = (targetKey, action) => {
    add([action](targetKey));
    remove([action](targetKey));
  };

  return (
             <Tabs
                  type='editable-card'
                  onChange={onChange}
                  activeKey={activeKey}
                  onEdit={onEdit}
                >
                  {panes.map((pane) => (
                    <TabPane
                      tab={pane.title}
                      key={pane.key}
                      closable={pane.closable}
                    >
                      {pane.content}
                    </TabPane>
                  ))}
                </Tabs>
  );
};

export default Curriculum;
```

To be precise how do I write this class code inside a function. My onEdit, add and remove function inside the function is not working

```
onEdit = (targetKey, action) => {
    this[action](targetKey);
  };

  add = () => {
    const { panes } = this.state;
    const activeKey = `newTab${this.newTabIndex++}`;
    panes.push({ title: 'New Tab', content: 'New Tab Pane', key: activeKey });
    this.setState({ panes, activeKey });
  };

  remove = targetKey => {
    let { activeKey } = this.state;
    let lastIndex;
    this.state.panes.forEach((pane, i) => {
      if (pane.key === targetKey) {
        lastIndex = i - 1;
      }
    });
    const panes = this.state.panes.filter(pane => pane.key !== targetKey);
    if (panes.length && activeKey === targetKey) {
      if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        activeKey = panes[lastIndex].key;
      } else {
        activeKey = panes[0].key;
      }
    }
    this.setState({ panes, activeKey });
  };
```

I want a similar functionality but the code must be inside a function not class
[See the CodeSand box Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/w80xk?file=/index.js:0-1998)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created functional component for you  [functional component](https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-trigger-of-new-tab-antd4130-forked-83cbl)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Tabs, Button } from "and";

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const Demo = () => {
  const initPanes = [
{ title: "Tab 1", content: "Content of Tab Pane 1", key: "1" },
{ title: "Tab 2", content: "Content of Tab Pane 2", key: "2" }
];
 const [panes, setPanes] = useState(initPanes);
 const [newTabIndex, setNewTabIndex] = useState(0);
 const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(panes[0].key);

const onChange = (activeKey) => {
 setActiveKey(activeKey);
};

 const onEdit = (targetKey, action) => {
  if (action === "remove") {
  remove(targetKey);
  }
 };

const add = () => {
let newTabIndex2 = newTabIndex + 1;
let key = `newTab${newTabIndex2}`;
panes.push({ title: "New Tab", content: "New Tab Pane", key: key });
setPanes(panes);
setActiveKey(key);
setNewTabIndex(newTabIndex2);
};

const remove = (targetKey) => {
let lastIndex;
panes.forEach((pane, i) => {
  if (pane.key === targetKey) {
    lastIndex = i - 1;
  }
});

const newPanes = panes.filter((pane) => pane.key !== targetKey);
if (panes.length && activeKey === targetKey) {
  if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    setActiveKey(panes[lastIndex].key);
  } else {
    setActiveKey(panes[0].key);
  }
}
setPanes(newPanes);
};

return (
<div>
  <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
    <Button onClick={add}>ADD</Button>
  </div>
  <Tabs
    hideAdd
    onChange={onChange}
    activeKey={activeKey}
    type="editable-card"
    onEdit={onEdit}
  >
    {panes.map((pane) => (
      <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
        {pane.content}
      </TabPane>
    ))}
  </Tabs>
</div>
);
};
ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: this code is working fine but removing all the tabs is throwing an error as no Key is available after removing all the tabs.

Comment: oops, I forgot this case, 
there are 2 possible solutions.
1. update this line if you want to let the user delete all tabs :... const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(panes.length > 0 && panes[0].key);

2. else if you want to restrict the user to delete the last one tab then add if condition in the remove function as  updated in the sandbox

Comment: can you cover this other condition too? I'm also facing the same issue.